# Sum column in Excel from 1 value in a separate column until a different value in the criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

I am trying to sum a column A based on a value in column B, but I only want to sum the values until I reach a different criteria value (in column B).  When I reach that value, I want to reset the function & repeat.

| A | B | Sum Value I'm looking for |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | N/A | 12 |
| 34 | N/A | 46 |
| 21 | N/A | 67 |
| 45 | BREAK | 109 |
| 232 | N/A | 232 |
| 64 | N/A | 296 |
| 231 | BREAK | 527 |
| 423 | BREAK | 423 |
| 46 | N/A | 46 |
| 4 | N/A | 50 |
| 56 | N/A | 106 |
| 86 | N/A | 192 |
| 235 | N/A | 427 |
| 463 | BREAK | 890 |
| 3 | N/A | 3 |
| 57 | N/A | 60 |
| 75 | BREAK | 135 |
|  |  |  |

I have tried SUMIF but cannot get this to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is 'BREAK' a value on column B? If yes, should the value in A on the row BREAK count for the sequence above or below that?

Answer (score 3):

The following formula should work:

```
=SUM(A$2:A2)-SUMIF(B$1:B1,"BREAK",C$1:C1)
```

And populate down

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've started using this formula (in cell C2):

```
=IF(B2="BREAK";A3;C2+A3)
```

This is not entirely correct, but it gives another idea: in order to repeat the calculation of the whole sum, you do this in an cumulative manner (first you get A2+A3 (which you put in cell C2), then A2+A3+A4 (which you put in cell C3), ...).